# Fancybox 3 CSS for Thumbnail Sidebar

Tags: fancybox-3

How can I change the color of the thumbnail side bar from white to black?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using CSS, for example:

```
.fancybox-thumbs {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POgEMb

Comment: If you are going to answer a question, it would be great if you took a moment to edit it.  Also, if the question was worth answering, isn't it likely worth an upvote? Thanks and Cheers.